# How can I combine two SQL queries using INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have 2 SQL queries as below:

```
$results2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE id IN (".implode(",", $product_ids).")");
$getprice = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='_regular_price' AND post_id IN (".implode(",", $product_ids).")");
```

I have combined them as below query:

```
$yeni = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                            FROM wp_posts 
                            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id 
                            WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                            WHERE wp_posts.id IN (".implode(",", $product_ids).")");
```

After combining the queries, it's giving an empty result. I can't find the issue with the updated query.

Comment: Add sample data from both table and also your expected output from them. This would help. Also tag your database name.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sql.
I have replace this `WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price'`

```
$yeni = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE wp_posts.id IN (".implode(",", $product_ids).") and wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't use the native Wordpress features via OOP procedure.
Your simple query, it can be translated like this:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'page', // post type: page, post, attachment etc..
        'post__in' => $productIds, // array[]
        )
    );
// after that, you can use a standard wordpress loop
if($loop->have_posts()) {
    while($loop->have_posts()) {
        : $loop->the_post();
        the_title();
        print "<br>";
        // access to meta key _regular_price
        print get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
    }
}
```

This is the right way.
Cheers

Class reference here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/